# Applying mathematical operation between rows of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, performance, vectorization

Let's assume we have two numpy arrays A (n1xm) and B (n2xm) and I want to apply a certain mathematical operation between the rows of both tables.

For example, let's say that we want to calculate the Euclidean distance between each row of A and each row of B and store it at a new numpy table C (n1xn2).

The simple for-loop approach would be something like the following:

```
C = np.zeros((A.shape[0],B.shape[0]))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
  for j in range(B.shape[0]):
    C[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(A[i]-B[j])
```

However, the above implementation is not the most efficient. How could I write this differently by using vectorization to speed up the implementation ?

Comment: [`np.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) has an axis parameter `np.linalg.norm(A[:,None] - B, axis=2)`. `diff = A[:,None] - B; np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', diff, diff)**.5` is about twice as fast for larger arrays. *x,y* are not defined or mentioned, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast over a new axis:

```
# n1 x m x n2
diff = A[:, :, None] - B[:, :, None].T

# n1 x n2 after summing across m
dists = np.sqrt((diff * diff).sum(1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I can also write ```diff**2``` rather than ```diff * diff```, right ?